# MySQL get ids of the range between two conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I've a table

```
+----+------------+
| id | condition  |
+----+------------+
| 1  | open       |
+----+------------+
| 2  | content    |
+----+------------+
| 3  | content    |
+----+------------+
| 4  | close      |
+----+------------+
| 5  | nocontentx |
+----+------------+
| 6  | nocontenty |
+----+------------+
| 7  | open       |
+----+------------+
| 8  | content    |
+----+------------+
| 9  | close      |
+----+------------+
| 10 | nocontentz |
+----+------------+
| 11 | open       |
+----+------------+
| 12 | content    |
+----+------------+
```

and want to get a new table where I get the IDs (the first and the last) of the values between "`close`" and "`open`". Note that the values between this two conditions are dynamic (I can't search by `"nocontent"whatever`)

Such as I get this table:

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | start_id | end_id |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | 5        | 6      |
+----+----------+--------+
| 2  | 10       | 10     |
+----+----------+--------+
```

Thanks in advance!

**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c255c8/2**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id,
       id as startid,
       (select id
        from atable a2
        where a2.id > a.id and
              a2.condition = 'close'
        order by a2.id asc
        limit 1
       ) as end_id
from atable a cross join
     (select @rn := 0) vars
where a.condition = 'open';
```

The working SQL Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c255c8/5).

Note this returns the third `open` as well.  If you don't want it, then add `having end_id is not null` to the end of the query.

EDIT:

If you know the ids are sequential, you can just add and subtract 1 from the above query:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id,
       id+1 as startid,
       (select id
        from atable a2
        where a2.id > a.id and
              a2.condition = 'open'
        order by a2.id asc
        limit 1
       ) - 1 as end_id
from atable a cross join
     (select @rn := 0) vars
where a.condition = 'close';
```

You can also do this in a different way, which is by counting the number of open and closes before any given row and using this as a group identifier.  The way your data is structured, every other group is what you are looking for:

```
select grp, min(id), max(id)
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(t2.condition in ('open', 'close'))
              from t t2
              where t2.id <= t.id
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where t.condition not in ('open', 'close') and
      grp % 2 = 0
group by grp;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. First, `select id` needs to be `select min(id)` so it only returns one ID. But it's returning the wrong IDs. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01de5/2

Comment: he wants the IDs of the first and last row BETWEEN `close` and `open`, he doesn't want the IDs of the `close` and `open` rows themselves.

Comment: @kairos . . . I must've changed the `asc` to `desc` and it got stuck that way.  The right sort order is `asc`.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c255c8/8 with asc is not working either since it gives me the IDs between open and close and not the opposite (between close and open) :( sorry

Comment: Even if I invert the two conditions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c255c8/9 I've to remove the first and last IDs since I just want the IDs outside those markers

Comment: @kairos . . . Do you know that the ids are sequential with no gaps?

Comment: @kairos . . . The last two queries should work -- tested, to the best of my understanding of your problem (which is much better now thanks to your comments).

Comment: that's perfect! Many Thks!!